# Chrome headless- How to set a delay for rendering javascript chart?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to convert a HTML file to a PDF file. Now I am using chrome headless.

I am following this https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

And when I enter this command :

```
google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf https://www.chromestatus.com/
```

Sometimes it shows like this :

[image]

I tried with the other pages but they are same.

I think it needs a delay to render the javascript chart.

Is there any way to set a delay for converting?

Comment: [See this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614437/make-chrome-headless-to-wait-for-ajax-before-printing-to-pdf)
This worked for me.