# Make Chrome Headless to Wait for Ajax Before Printing to PDF

Tags: headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to use chrome headless to print my webpage to a PDF file.
The PDf file is with no data, because the headless chrome is printing it before the ajax commands finish.

Any idea on how I can get it to wait?

Here's the command I currently use:

```
chrome --headless http://localhost:8080/banana/key --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --print-to-pdf=C:\\tmp\\tmp.pdf
```

Comment: A quick Google search shows that a few other people have run into this issue too. Have you explored using [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#puppeteer) to programmatically run Chrome Headless instead? It may expose properties such as requests in flight that you can use to control your delay, or if you wish you could even manually include a timed delay yourself.

Comment: @MikeHill Puppeteer looks like the way to go, thanks for the suggestion! It can wait for the page to load, and network idle, plus you get full control over the PDF layout.

Answer (score 65):

```
chrome --headless http://localhost:8080/banana/key --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --print-to-pdf=C:\\tmp\\tmp.pdf --virtual-time-budget=10000
```

Try this, `virtual-time-budget` is the parameter which can delay it.

Comment: This also has a positive effect on Web Fonts, even when the fonts are loaded from the local disk. Otherwise Chrome seems to have problems loading *some* Web Fonts in time... strange world.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for pointing this out. Thinking about it it's obvious that Chrome cannot guess when the page is actually ready for a screenshot.

Comment: --virtual-time-budget is in milliseconds, just for future reference

Comment: @Ivan: The argument specifies the maximum time chrome is waiting (10000 ms in this case). It will continue sooner, if page loading has completed sooner.

Comment: This successfully waits until Google Fonts are being loaded that are referenced within a CSS file via @import.

Comment: there is also a `--timeout` option but did not really worked for me same as `--virtual-time-budget`

Comment: The options are explained here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PppegrpXhOzKKAuNlP6XOEnviXFGUiX2hop00Cxcv4o/edit#